# Converting iterated calculation to iterator -- what's this called?

Tags: loops, iterator, generator, lazy-evaluation, code-conversion

This must be a common code conversion, so I am surprised that I cannot easily find what it is called nor info on how best to do it.

Original code (pseudo):

```
sub generate_array {
  for(i=0,n=0;i<X;++i)
    for(j=0;j<Y;++j)
      for(k=0;k<p[i][j];++k,++n)
        a[n] = calculation(i,j,k,n,p);
  return a;
}

m=generate_array();
for(i=0;i<size(m);++i)
  if (some_cond(m[i]) break;
  work_with(m[i]);
```

For time-efficiency reasons, I want to lazy-eval the array instead thus:

```
sub array_start() {...}
sub array_next() {... return val}

array_start();
while (m = array_next())
  if some_cond(m) break;
  work_with(m);
```

Yes, it's called "lazy evaluation" generally (design pattern), but isn't this specific and basic type of code conversion called something more specific? I've also looked up "iterator" and "factory" design patterns, and "loop unrolling", but nothing is a good conceptual fit to what I'm talking about. Any ideas? What am I missing? Guidance appreciated.

**Update**

The answer is "**generator**" as given below. As for the "conversion" of code, the core change from above would be `a[n] =` --> `yield`, and of course using whatever syntax defines a generator rather than a subroutine. But it's also possible to implement the idea "by hand" (at least for this simple case), if your language doesn't support it and/or you don't want to use a 3rd-party package to implement it, by "unnesting" all the loops:

```
sub array_next {
  if (++k >= p[i][j])
    k = 0;
    if (++j >= Y)
      j = 0;
      if (++i >= X)
        return false
  return calculation(i,j,k,p)
}

sub array_start {
  i = j = k = 0;
}
```

Note a difference that needs to be handled correctly though: the variables (`i`, `j`, `k`) have become global, or at least exposed.

Comment: enumerator? i think (may be wrong) that MoveNext, MovePrev, Start, End belongs to the Enumerator style/name...

Comment: Thanks. So far I only find that "enumerator" is described as an implementation interface for "iterator" and is always tied to an existing enumerable collection (rather than a lazily-calculated value), but maybe there is more...

Comment: myeah there's no real term here... you're basically just looping through an array, and checking a condition... nothing special or specific about that. I thought you were referring to the way you were looping (MoveNext instead of For Loop)... sorry i can't help you more than this.

Comment: Right; sorry the func names above may have confused -- there is no "array" as such in the converted implementation. The idea is to *not* calculate any such array, only its elements one by one (thus avoiding expensive calculations of values that may never be used).

Comment: ok... if you find out what that term is, let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing here is not exactly **lazy evaluation** because it usually refers to the delayed evaluation of a certain expression, which is common in functional programming. From the Wikipedia article on [Lazy Evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation):

> [...] lazy evaluation, or call-by-need is an evaluation strategy which
>   delays the evaluation of an expression until its value is needed [...]

What you are building here fits very well the term **generator**. From the Wikipedia article on [Generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generator_%28computer_programming%29):

> [...] a generator is a special routine that can be used to control the
>   iteration behaviour of a loop. In fact, all generators are
>   iterators. A generator is very similar to a function that returns
>   an array, in that a generator has parameters, can be called, and
>   generates a sequence of values. However, instead of building an array
>   containing all the values and returning them all at once, a generator
>   yields the values one at a time, which requires less memory and allows
>   the caller to get started processing the first few values immediately.

If the sequence being generated is infinite, the generator is often referred to as a **stream**. However, the term stream is also used for finite sequences that are computed on demand.

Comment: Yes, this is it! As a purist (and for my own education, and efficiency control), I will implement the concept for myself in the code above, by unnesting all the loops, rather than find a package that gives me a `yield` capability. But it is good to know that this design need has previously been recognized, named, and solved!